# HTML/CSS: Using position absolute to stick to the side, when there is a horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have a **div** that needs to stick to the right side of the page. I have accomplished this using **position:absolute**, and setting the **right** and **top** attributes.

It looks something like this:
[image: Img 1]

Now this solution is great! But today, we ran into some problems.
If the screen is so small that it creates a horizontal scrollbar, this will happen (Pay attention to the scrollbar at the bottom if you dont understand the problem :) ):
[image: Img 2]
[image: Img 3]

It is sticking to the right side of the window instead of the document - which would actually be okay, but unfourtantly as soon as you move the scrollbar, you'll see that it only sticks to the **intially loaded** window..

So I need the div to stick to the right side of the document, rather than the window..

I cannot use fixed. Can anyone see a solution for this? I feel lost.

Here is an [Jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zq8hjt7j/1/)

```
<div style="background-color:red;
width:50px;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
top:20px;
right:0%;">
    test
</div>
```

**A jQuery/JavaScript solution is welcome! Aslong as its not a massive library :)**

Comment: Why can't you use `fixed`? It's the easier solution for this.

Comment: `position:absolute` and `position:fixed` would produce two different results. the second would cause the bar to stay on-screen even when scrolling down (this is what i consider to be "sticky"), the first would not. which is your intended purpose?

Comment: @Utkanos, nope but CSS3 solutions are welcome!.. (I know, its a stretch :))

Comment: @LcSalazar As woodrow says, fixed gives a different result. I dont mind it sticking on the x-axis but it **cannot** stick on the y-axis :)

Comment: Try using some percentage instead of pixel because as the width and height of screen are different for different users so if you will use them on the basis of percentage like 100% then it will make it just 100% right or left what you want to specify ... which will work fine for you

Comment: @ShashankSharma Is this http://jsfiddle.net/zq8hjt7j/ what you mean? Cause it does not work unfourtantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Jquery's `.scrollLeft()` function.

http://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/

Attach an event listener to the window `scroll` event, and adjust the div's horizontal position according to the window's width, and window's horizontal scroll.

Something like this:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var vW = $(window).width();
    var vS = $(window).scrollLeft();
    var dvW = $("#dv1").width();

    $("#dv1").css("left", vW - dvW + vS);
});
```

[**Updated working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zq8hjt7j/2/)

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! Just what i was looking for! I figured that it would be impossible to do with plain CSS, but this is fine!

Comment: It's totally possible with CSS.

Comment: Actually it should look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zq8hjt7j/4/ cause you need to take into account the `resize`, not only the `scroll`. Also you should cache whatever you can, from elements to static widths (see fiddle). In any case it's completely buggy. See on horiz. resize what happens.

Answer (score 1):

use one container div with

```
{width:100%; position:absolute; top:50px; left:0px; }
```

in that div put your div and set

```
{float:right; width:80px; height:300px;}
```

ng Thomas

Comment: This makes no sense. The "container" would fall into the same issue the OP's div.

Comment: There is a lot of extra JS animation code linked together with this box, so I want to avoid that kind of solution

If there is no other choice, I'll have to go with that.. (It is a very big site, and the solution has to be as sleek as possible)

Thanks for your answer though! Might be the only solution :)

Comment: @lcSalazar No it doesn't. Cause the, 100% div will change his width if the windowsize is changed!      At benjamin: i think this will be the easiest and a  sleek solution!

Comment: Thomas, the problem here is not the *window*'s width, but the *document*'s width. Otherwise, the OP already had a `position: absolute` div placed at `right: 0`, would work as well as yours... but that's not the case when you scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, a simple thing made complicated. The horizontal scroll bars kick in, not because of the absolute positioned element, but because the padding or the margin you're using on the content to not cover itself when the viewport is smaller.

This is corrected by using box-sizing:border-box on the content and using padding, not margin to make a space for it.

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/wulih/1/

**EDIT: http://jsbin.com/wulih/1/edit**

**DEMO CSS:**

```
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
}
.content {
    padding: 0 70px 20px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

DEMO HTML:

```
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="content">
   <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
   <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>
   <h2>Header Level 2</h2>
   <ol>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
   </ol>
   <blockquote>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
   </blockquote>
   <h3>Header Level 3</h3>
   <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
   </ul>
   <pre><code>
#header h1 a { 
    display: block; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you serious? I didn't ask how to fix the horizontal scrollbar - its there for a reason, out of my power. This is a big website, made by several people - design decisions has been made by lots of people.

Comment: Sorry if that sounded harsh :) I guess I didnt explain it right in the question. My bad! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Typically horizontal scroll bars are undesirable, especially on smaller viewports such as touch devices as you can't see scrollbars until the user actually drags in that direction.

Comment: I know. We have a mobile breakpoint that is 600px - so between 600px and 900px, the website will have a scrollbar. it is a very very *very* large website, so compromises has to be made unfourtantly. And they are completely out of my control :)

Comment: Wow. +1 for the effort! Your *Responsive* suggestions are something that today is almost a *must-have*. JS is not needed for that task (see related issue on my comment at LcSalazar's answer) and CSS3 might get involved. Or it's simply an *issue by-design* that sadly, in big projects (as mentioned by OP) it's almost like building a bug over a bug and trying to fix it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - thanks. 'Design by committee' is always a sad way to go.